# Automatic login after clicking on the link with the token (jrean/laravel-user-verification)

Tags: php, laravel, verification, autoblogged

I use the "jrean/laravel-user-verification" package. When I click on the link with the token I want to redirect in my homepage and be already logged. How can I implement this? Thank you)

Laravel: **5.4**
Package Version: **4.1**

Comment: Please add some code. Read the guide for how to ask good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, but I used out of the box Laravel Auth and do not rewrite any code in "jrean/laravel-user-verification" package. It have no sense to copy standard code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this problem. Add to my **register** function (RegisterController) **event**:

```
public function register(VerificationRequest $request)
 {
       ...
       event(new Registered($user));
       ...
 }
```

Сreate **listener**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
use Jrean\UserVerification\Events\UserVerified;

/**
 * Class UserVerifiedListener
 * @package App\Listeners
 */
class UserVerifiedListener
{
    /**
     * @var AuthManager
     */
    private $auth;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @param AuthManager $auth
     */
    public function __construct(AuthManager $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserVerified  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserVerified $event)
    {
        $this->auth->guard()->login($event->user);
    }
}
```

And register it in :

```
app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Listeners\UserVerifiedListener;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Jrean\UserVerification\Events\UserVerified;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        UserVerified::class => [
            UserVerifiedListener::class
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        //
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(UserVerifiedListener::class, function () {
            return new UserVerifiedListener(
                $this->app->make('auth')
            );
        });
    }
}
```